# How to get value of textbox after ajax post using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting undefined as a value using the code below when I try to get the value of a textbox after a post. Is this possible or am I missing something basic?

```
<input type="text" size="3" value="<?php echo $item['qty'] ?>" id="quantity[<?php echo $sizeid?>]" name="quantity[<?php echo $sizeid?>]">

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "bin/process_updateqty.php",
dataType: 'json',
data: dataString,
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        alert($('#quantity['+key+']').val());
    });
 }
```

});

Comment: Are you saying that your return data is undefined?  Have you parsed your json repsonse?

data = $.parseJSON(data) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers.  I figured it out.

The answer to the original question is - YES, you can reference a textbox after a postback.  The issue was I was referencing a textbox array incorrectly.

I was originally referencing the textbox like this:

```
$('#quantity['+key+']').val()
```

However I should have been referencing the textbox this way:

```
$('input[name="quantity['+key+']"]').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your success function will use the `key` from the `each` iterator- [0,1,2...], so your query selector is:

```
#quantity[0], #quantity[1], (etc)
```

Is this what you intended?

I think not.  I think you probably wanted:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    alert($(value).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We need some of your HTML, or at least the output of this (which is used for your `id`):

```
<?php echo $sizeid?>
```

In fact, as RSG says, the `$.each` method is used to iterate over an array, so in your function, the `key` parameter **is the index** of the element that is passed with the `value` parameter, as [you can read in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Also, are you sure that your `data` object is actually an array?